# Enabling Reverse Proxy without Application Request Routing (ARR) on IIS 7.x

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, dmz

There are few questions around Reverse Proxy on Server in Presentation Zone (PZ).

1. I'm trying to setup a reverse proxy on the IIS 7.x Windows 2012 Server(PZ). Do we really need ARR plugin to configure Reverse Proxy? Can you please suggest enable reverse proxy on the IIS 7.x without using ARR?
2. Is there any option to enable reverse proxy even without URL Re writer also?
3. How rewriting rules can be validated, captured, and maintained? asking this in context of deployment perspective.

Comment: Mistake 3, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

1. ARRProxy is Microsoft's load balancing / reverse proxy solution. There are of course 3rd party solutions, like haProxy / nGinx, so you need it for a reverse proxy implementation unless you are going to use one of those.
2. You need the URL rewrite module, AFAIK.
3. Not sure. I guess you could have some unit testing on web.config where the rules are stored in the rules node?

Comment: Thanks Maatthew. Is it really required to have ARR installed? can't we just do it with URL rewriter alone?

Comment: Its been a while, but I remember it was an installation requirement. Why wouldn't you want to install it out of interest

Comment: Setting the server as reverse proxy ( for load balancing and security). Primarily, diverting the traffic from internet world to intranet servers( secure zone)

Comment: Yes I understand what you want ARR for, but not sure why you dont want to install Url Rewrite. It's pretty useful...

Comment: @MattEvans It is the other way around. The OP wants Url rewrite but not the whole ARR.

Comment: @Matt Evans - ARR doesn't support TLS 1.2 which is the reason why I don't want it.